# R Markdown - how to include hash tags in a Rmd document so they render correctly in a markdown (.md) document

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am using RStudio and RMarkdown to prepare markdown documents (.md files).

I would like to include hash tags (#tags) within the text of my document.

Rendering my RMarkdown document turns #tag to \#tag in the .md file.

Is it possible for the text "#tag" to be rendered without the escape backslash? Thanks.

Comment: I just tried `&#35;Hello`,  `\#Hello` and `#Hello`. All three options give me `#Hello` in the final output.

Comment: Hi @stefan. I get \#Hello, \#Hello and \#Hello with the examples you give.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was the following (i.e., the Pandoc feature called raw attributes) which here renders as `#tag` in the .md file.

```
---
title: "Basic Stats"
output: md_document
---

this is a `#tag`{=markdown}.
```

Many thanks to Christophe Dervieux at RStudio for the help (https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-to-include-hash-tags-in-a-rmd-document-so-they-render-correctly-in-a-markdown-md-document/92480)